# Fatty Acid synthesis - enzymes that vertebrates cannot make

Tags: biochemistry

In the fatty acid elongation and desaturation reactions, how are enzymes that insert double bonds after the 9th carbon different from those that insert  at the 9th or before? Vertebrates (at least mammals) don't have these enzymes.